# asp.net core scaffolding issue

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am working on asp.net core project. I have created a model with its attribute and also have created a key in the model.
When I am trying to scaffold using the entity framework which adds controller and view I am getting error. Please find the error attached with this question.

.csproj File Code:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
    <SccProjectName>SAK</SccProjectName>
    <SccProvider>SAK</SccProvider>
    <SccAuxPath>SAK</SccAuxPath>
    <SccLocalPath>SAK</SccLocalPath>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net452</TargetFramework>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>win7-x86</RuntimeIdentifier>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <UserSecretsId>aspnet-webapplication</UserSecretsId>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="wwwroot\css\animate.min.css" />
    <Content Include="wwwroot\lib\moment\moment.min.js" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="1.1.1" PrivateAssets="All" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design" Version="1.1.1" PrivateAssets="All" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="1.1.0" PrivateAssets="All" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="1.1.0" PrivateAssets="All" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink" Version="1.1.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="1.0.0" />
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools" Version="1.0.0" />
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="1.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

[image: Error Image]

Comment: Did you try with command line? Can you share the code?

Comment: As Anuraj said, can you please share code - `project.json` or `.csproj`?

Comment: That looks like an issue with Visual Studio, not EF Core. You may want to try repairing or reinstalling it.

Comment: @Sanket Please find my .csproj code attached to the post.

Comment: @Anuraj Yes I did tried command line as well.

Comment: @chat007 Are you getting the same error in command line as well?

Comment: @Anuraj I am not sure with command line as I can't get any good article showing this for Visual studio 17 as we have now .csproj instead of project.json. If you have any article about it then I can give it a go.

Comment: This seems to be issue with WebCodeGeneration tool & not EF core